# SqlCeDataAdapter.Fill method causes application to exit silently

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have a call to SqlCeDataAdapater. Fill with a DataSet that kills my app with no exception.  It only seems to happen when I attempt to load in a large number of records (approx 30,000 rows).   I get nothing in the debugger the app just dies with no exceptions.  I've checked the mem usage and there is more than enough memory available to load the data, in fact in some instances you can load the data dependent on the size of the last table loaded.  It makes no sense to me, I can run the same app on the desktop with no problems but fails consistently on my Windows CE device.

SQL Server Compact Edition v3.5
Compact Framework v3.5
Visual Studio 2008
Windows CE 6.0

Comment: Would the large number of rows be more than 32 767, by any chance?

Comment: No it's slightly less than 30, 000.  Rather annoyingly if I load each table into a different dataSet or DataTable it works fine, although it pretty much eats up all my available memory.  The issue only seems to happen when I try and discard data read from a table before reading the next

Answer (score 0):

This question might be similar to yours. [sql ce native exception 0xc0000005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154488/sql-ce-native-exception-0xc0000005/11744643#11744643)

In my case I found that the SQL CE installation was corrupt so removing it completely (including your deployed dlls) and re-install worked.