# sql ce native exception 0xc0000005

Tags: c#, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

When i run my .net 3.5 cf application that reads some data from ms sql ce, sometimes i get an native exception with the following info:

```
ExceptionCode: 0xc0000005
ExceptionAddress : 0x44746e65 (variable)
Reading: 0x44746e64

at NativeMethods.GetKeyInfo(IntPtr pTx, String pwszBaseTable, IntPtr prgDbKeyInfo, Int32 cDbKeyInfo, IntPtr pError)

at SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBahavior behavior)

(... omitted for brevity)

at dadosGpsTableAdapter.GetDadosAEnviar()
```

My GetDadosAEnviar query is very simple:

```
SELECT        _id, Latitude, Longitude, Ignicao, Altitude, Velocidade,Direcao, Qualidade, Timestamp, Valido, Enviado, CondutorID
FROM            DadosGps
WHERE        (Enviado = 0)
```

and the code that calls this query is:

```
private bool SendRemainingData()
    {
        SetCurrentStatus("A Enviar historico");
        try
        {

            lock (lockObj)
            {
                DadosDataSet.DadosGpsDataTable dadosAEnviar = gpsAdapter.GetDadosEnviar();

                if (dadosAEnviar.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    foreach (DadosDataSet.DadosGpsRow amostra in dadosAEnviar.Rows)
                    {
                        bool resultado = webServicesGps.SendToServerGPSData(IMEI, amostra.Timestamp, amostra.Latitude, amostra.Longitude, Convert.ToDecimal(amostra.Altitude),
                            Convert.ToDecimal(amostra.Velocidade), Convert.ToDecimal(amostra.Direcao), new bool[] { amostra.Ignicao }, decimal.Zero, Convert.ToDecimal(amostra.Qualidade), "");

                        if (resultado)
                            gpsAdapter.RegistarEnvio(amostra._id);
                    }
                }
                dadosAEnviar.Dispose();
            }

(... omitted for brevity)
```

As you can see for the previous research i was indicated that it could be an sync issue between threads, so i use the lock statement with an

```
private static object lockObj=new object();
```

But the problem is when it calls the GetDadosAEnviar. What i can do to correct this behavior?

***UPDATE***

After more extensive debbuging i framed the code that causes the exception, it's on the auto-generated code vs creates:

```
this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[3];
        DadosDataSet.DadosGpsDataTable dataTable = new DadosDataSet.DadosGpsDataTable();
        //Next line "barfs" an native exception
        this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED IT**

The error was caused by corruption of the sqlce native dll. By uninstalling and re-installing the sqlce everything worked. Better yet it is quicker, because of the time spent on optimizing the flow of code, instead of using stock VS boilerplate code

Answer (score 1):

Is the SqlCeConnection being used at the same time on another thread?

If that is the case, you may need a lock there too.  To test, make a new connection (temporarily) and see if it fixes it.

Comment: it doesn't work. The error is in the vs2008 auto-generated code , when it attempts to call an the dataAdapter.fill method. See the updated post, with the code that "barfs" the exception

Comment: Did you try putting a lock around every place you use a DataTable, or did you try opening a new connection in every place?

Comment: create new connection, do stuff, close connection. But i was able to solve it by removing the sqlce installation and install it again

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error and was pulling my hair out with frustration, not getting anywhere. I references the SQL CE dlls directly and copied them all to the device during deploy, so after I read the above solution I tried to remove all the files and redeploy from scratch. That also did not work. In the end I installed SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 directly on to the device with the CAB file found in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact 
>   Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\armv4i\sqlce.wce5.armv4i.cab

(ARMv4 in my case, your's may vary). After installing this to the device everything ran fine.